# Is mongodb "_id" index always kept in cache?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I've a mongodb database which has multiple collections. There's one additional collection, which is more like a log of all events that happen in the system. I am wondering, when I've a large collection which is rarely used, is "_id" index of that collection also put into RAM when no operations happen on that collection ? Or it simply waits on the disk until a read operation in executed.
My main concern is if this collection's size affects performance of other queries (due to size of the collection a few time larger than available RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll be swapped out on an [LRU basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU)).

> Indexes do not have to fit entirely into RAM in all cases. If the value of the indexed field increments with every insert, and most queries select recently added documents; then MongoDB only needs to keep the parts of the index that hold the most recent or “right-most” values in RAM.
>
> To ensure this index fits in RAM, you must not only have more than that much RAM available but also must have RAM available for the rest of the [working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-working-set).
> The indexes and the working set must be able to fit in memory at the same time.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/#indexing-right-handed